# pandas combine specific excel sheets into one

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have an excel sheet named `output.xlsx` with multiple sheets in it.

Example, the sheets within it are named as `P1`,`P2`,`P3`,`P4`

I would like to do the below

a) Combine sheet `P1` and sheet `P2` into one single sheet name it as `P1&P2`

b) retain the `P3` and `P4` sheets in `output.xlsx` as it is. No changes

c) Overwrite the same file `output.xlsx` but don't touch `P3` and `P4`

So, I tried the below

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel('output.xlsx', sheet_name=['P1','P2']), ignore_index=True)

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="P1&P2",index=False)
```

But the above code ovcerwrites the file and deletes other sheet

How can I combine only the sheets `P1` and `P2` and keep `P3` and `P4` as it is

Comment: We have mode option in ExcelWriter, Did you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `openpyxl` instead of `pandas`:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Load workbook
wb = load_workbook('output.xlsx')

# Copy rows from P2 to P1
for row in wb['P2'].iter_rows(2):  # skip header
    wb['P1'].append([cell. value for cell in row])

# Remove P2
wb.remove(wb['P2'])

# Rename P1 to P1P2
wb['P1'].title = 'P1P2'

# Save to another file, just to be sure
wb.save('output2.xlsx')
```